# Not able to connect xperia tipo to Ubuntu

Tags: usb, connection-issues, sony-xperia-tipo

I can connect my Xperia Tipo to Windows but not able to connect Ubuntu. Why is it so? Is there any changes that I need to make to my phone ?

Comment: What do you want to connect (USB storage, ADB, ...)? What happens when you connect your device to Ubuntu? Anything appearing? Did you check with the `lsusb` command if the device was recognized? Most likely some [UDev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rules are missing (your device not being known to the system). Though that should not matter to the USB storage.

Comment: Do you have the drivers installed on Ubuntu? For windows most Xperia devices automatically install drivers, it doesn't happen on Ubuntu..

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to come up every few weeks...

Ubuntu 10 (and sometimes above) requires [manual editing of your udev config](http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-android-sd-card-ubuntu/) in order to recognize an Android device.

As root create the text file "/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules” and add this line for a Sony device:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="054c", MODE="0666"
```

Save the file and exit the editor, then set the permissions of the file and tell the udev system to reload the rules:

```
$ sudo chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your phone is not in mass-storage-mode. Go to

```
settings / XPeria / connectivity
```

and set USB connection mode to *mass-storage*.

However, with this setting access is limited to the SD card; you won't be able to mount the internal memory.